# JQuery Nestable and Sortable restrict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-nestable

[image: J query Ne stable]

Hi, please help I am first time using J query Ne stable. i want to restrict Admin and Transported tabs should not drag. 
[enter link description here][2]
The Users in left users list only drag and drop below Admin and Transporter tabs in Roles list.

How to disable the drag functionality to only selected tabs

Comment: can you create a fiddle for your question? it will help to give solution little faster.

Comment: code in : https://jsfiddle.net/kpboda/qbk1jtap/16/

Comment: Have answered to this question by creating a JSFiddle by own.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1vcs0e47/

I have prepared this JSFiddle from demo link: https://dbushell.com/Nestable/

Things what I have did:
1) Added an input element, where in you can type list name like "Item 1", "Item 2" etc. (**Note: Text search is case sensitive, also this searched text is just for demo purpose, you can implement more better ideas for searching than I have used.**)

2) On change of an input element, we have found div with a class "dd-handle" and applied css "pointer-events" as property "none". Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

3) Draggable won't be applied to elements whose pointer-events are disabled and we did the same. Have also made nested listing too disabled.

4) A button to enable all disabled listing is given, just to test for instances.

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var updateOutput = function(e)
    {
        var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
            output = list.data('output');
        if (window.JSON) {
            output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));
        } else {
            output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
        }
    };

    // activate Nestable for list 1
    $('#nestable').nestable({
        group: 1
    })
    .on('change', updateOutput);

    // activate Nestable for list 2
    $('#nestable2').nestable({
        group: 1
    })
    .on('change', updateOutput);

    // output initial serialised data
    updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
    updateOutput($('#nestable2').data('output', $('#nestable2-output')));

    $('#nestable-menu').on('click', function(e)
    {
        var target = $(e.target),
            action = target.data('action');
        if (action === 'expand-all') {
            $('.dd').nestable('expandAll');
        }
        if (action === 'collapse-all') {
            $('.dd').nestable('collapseAll');
        }
    });

    $('#nestable3').nestable();
        $('#disabled_listname').on('change', function()
        {
                var disabling_listname = $.trim($(this).val());
                console.log('disabling_listname=', disabling_listname);
                console.log('element length=', $('div.dd-handle:contains("'+ disabling_listname +'")').length);
                if($('div.dd-handle:contains("'+ disabling_listname +'")').length > 0)
                {
            $('div.dd-handle:contains("'+ disabling_listname +'")').addClass('dd-handle-disable');
                    $('div.dd-handle:contains("'+ disabling_listname +'")').next('ol.dd-list').find('.dd-handle').addClass('dd-handle-disable');
                }
                if($('div.dd3-content:contains("'+ disabling_listname +'")').length > 0)
                { // just added this conditions for "Draggable Handles" example, only for demo purpose.
            $('div.dd3-content:contains("'+ disabling_listname +'")').parent().addClass('dd-handle-disable');
                    $('div.dd3-content:contains("'+ disabling_listname +'")').next('ol.dd-list').find('.dd-handle').addClass('dd-handle-disable');
                }
        });

        $('#enable_dragging').on('click', function()
        {
            $('.dd-handle-disable').removeClass('dd-handle-disable');
        });
});
```